# polygon fill is not semi transparent android maps v2

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I am using this code `.fillColor(Color.parseColor("0x7F00FF00"))`    and tried         `.fillColor(Color.argb(128, 255, 0, 0)` but the first one is not working and the second does not display any roads see through the polygon.How can I see the streets with polygon on top of it .

Note: The color is just to make out the difference but it should be transparent.

I appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was curious and tried exactly the same. But it works as expected. The polygon is transparent and streets etc. are still visible through the filled polygon.

I would check, whether the fillColor is set again later somewhere in your code to a non transparent color.

By the way, you do not need to use Color.parseColor() or Color argb() when passing constants.
In this case .fillColor(0x7F00FF00) will do it.

You can also change the color of the polygon after you have added it to the map:

```
Polygon polygon = map.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
polygon.setFillColor(0x7F00FF00);
```

Maybe you try that, to be sure, it is not overwritten.

Comment: Awesome "I would check, whether the fillColor is set again later somewhere in your code to a non transparent color." I completely forgot about this one .Thanks again.